# How to make file-like URLs on PHP site?

Tags: php, url

I have a site with a few PHP files responsible for showing all of the context. All of the URLs I have look like `...page.php?id=###`. Is it possible to assign some path to each `id` so that a visitor thinks that he is visiting static files?

Comment: What you're looking for is url rewriting. If you are running Apache as your webserver that would be `mod_rewrite`.  If you can provide a directory structure of your files I'm sure someone could provide more useful info.

Comment: Which kind of server is this about? What do you think is a static file? Would `...page.php/id/1234.html` be a static file for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [URLRewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) to rewrite e.g. `/page/##/` -> `page.php?id=##`:
See this guide [HERE](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the `mod_rewrite` in apache.

This generator might come in handy

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the easiest way is to use a path like `page.php/id/how-to-make-file-like-urls-on-php-site` and parse`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in your script.

Comment: Was thinking this is the best solution but it is damaging client-side URLs since the base of the file is changing :)